# Spring Integration: File Copy functionality with delay

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using following configuration to copy files from one directory to another directory -

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel fileInputChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "fileInputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "10000") )
public MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource() { 
    FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
    source.setDirectory(new File("C:/input_dir"));
    source.setFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter(".*"));
    return source;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fileInputChannel")
public FileWritingMessageHandler handle() {     
    FileWritingMessageHandler handler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File("C:/Output_dir"));
    handler.setDeleteSourceFiles(false);
    handler.setExpectReply(false);
    handler.setPreserveTimestamp(true);
    handler.setAsync(true);
    return handler;
}
```

I am expecting that :
- If there is any change in any source file OR 
- If a new file created in source directory 
updated OR newly created file will be updated/created in destination folder within 10 seconds. However it is taking more than 1 minute and file size in KBs. Also, source and destination directories are on same machine.
I am not able to identify why it is taking more than 1 minute when I have set @Poller time 10 seconds

---

logs -

```
[2017-01-31 10:33:04,943612]INFO [task-scheduler-3]  (FileReadingMessageSource.java:367) - Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=C:/input_dir/file.170126.19, headers={timestamp=1485876784308, id=662aaf51-91e5-6f78-a2a6-997fc01b8b79}]]<br>
[2017-01-31 10:33:04,943612]DEBUG[task-scheduler-3]  (AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:267) - Poll resulted in Message: GenericMessage [payload=C:/input_dir/file.170126.19, headers={timestamp=1485876784308, id=662aaf51-91e5-6f78-a2a6-997fc01b8b79}]<br>
[2017-01-31 10:33:04,943612]DEBUG[task-scheduler-3]  (AbstractMessageChannel.java:411) - preSend on channel 'fileInputChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=C:/input_dir/file.170126.19, headers={timestamp=1485876784308, id=662aaf51-91e5-6f78-a2a6-997fc01b8b79}]<br>
[2017-01-31 10:33:04,943612]DEBUG[task-scheduler-3]  (AbstractMessageHandler.java:115) - handle received message: GenericMessage [payload=C:/input_dir/file.170126.19, headers={timestamp=1485876784308, id=662aaf51-91e5-6f78-a2a6-997fc01b8b79}]<br>
[2017-01-31 10:33:04,943618]DEBUG[task-scheduler-3]  (AbstractMessageChannel.java:430) - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'fileInputChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=C:/input_dir/file.170126.19, headers={timestamp=1485876784308, id=662aaf51-91e5-6f78-a2a6-997fc01b8b79}]<br>
[2017-01-31 10:33:14,953620]INFO [task-scheduler-4]  (FileReadingMessageSource.java:367) - Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=C:/input_dir/file.170127.19, headers={timestamp=1485876794316, id=c05deaec-f863-fd7f-0b08-dd3534be81d7}]]<br>
[2017-01-31 10:33:14,953620]DEBUG[task-scheduler-4]  (AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:267) - Poll resulted in Message: GenericMessage [payload=C:/input_dir/file.170127.19, headers={timestamp=1485876794316, id=c05deaec-f863-fd7f-0b08-dd3534be81d7}]<br>
[2017-01-31 10:33:14,953620]DEBUG[task-scheduler-4]  (AbstractMessageChannel.java:411) - preSend on channel 'fileInputChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=C:/input_dir/file.170127.19, headers={timestamp=1485876794316, id=c05deaec-f863-fd7f-0b08-dd3534be81d7}]<br>
[2017-01-31 10:33:14,953620]DEBUG[task-scheduler-4]  (AbstractMessageHandler.java:115) - handle received message: GenericMessage [payload=C:/input_dir/file.170127.19, headers={timestamp=1485876794316, id=c05deaec-f863-fd7f-0b08-dd3534be81d7}]<br>
[2017-01-31 10:33:14,953626]DEBUG[task-scheduler-4]  (AbstractMessageChannel.java:430) - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'fileInputChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=C:/input_dir/file.170127.19, headers={timestamp=1485876794316, id=c05deaec-f863-fd7f-0b08-dd3534be81d7}]
```

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging for o.s.i.

Comment: Just tested your use-case on Windows as well. Files "travel" from dir to dir exactly during those 10 seconds...

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. DEBUG logs shows that there is interval of 10 seconds between each file. So if we are having 1000 files in input directory and update any file then it is possible that modified file will be reflected on destination after 10*1000 seconds

Comment: Hm, this SO service not always notify us. The `@Poller` has `maxMesaagesPerPoll` option. Make it as `-1` to poll as much files as possible per one polling task. Will come back to you with an answer tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I got your concern!

Look, `@Poller` has this property:

```
/**
 * @return The maximum number of messages to receive for each poll.
 * Can be specified as 'property placeholder', e.g. {@code ${poller.maxMessagesPerPoll}}.
 * Defaults to -1 (infinity) for polling consumers and 1 for polling inbound channel adapters.
 */
String maxMessagesPerPoll() default "";
```

Pay attention how it defaults to the "1 for polling inbound channel adapters".

So, to poll all your files per one polling task you really should make this property as infinity:

```
@Poller(maxMessagesPerPoll = "-1")
```